# When I use Windows Performance Timing, my Load Event End is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make a progress bar appear on my page as a PRELOADER. I can't quote seem to get the math right to make the progress bar use accurate percentages, so I've fallen back to using set timings.

So what I did was measured the loadtime of 1 image in my preloader, then based on the number of milliseconds that took to load, would add classes to my animations that basically either made it slow or fast.

Apologies if it's convoluted or not DRY. I'm a JS beginner.

Unfortunately, no matter how SLOW I made the connection via DevTools, I kept getting the 'very-fast' class. So I checked using the console, and I got these values, that don't make sense:

perfData.loadEventEnd: 0
perfData.loadEventStart: 1538796857083
LoadTime: -1538796857083

How is this possible? What's happening, and how can I fix?

I added my script before the end of the head, and put a onload="loadTime();" in the  used inside my preloader.

Here's the code:

```
        <script>
        // Measure Loadtime
        var loadTime = function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var perfData = window.performance.timing;
                var EstimatedTime = (perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart);

                if(EstimatedTime<1400){
                    $('#prefiller').addClass('fill-vfast')
                    console.log(perfData.loadEventEnd)
                    console.log(perfData.navigationStart)
                    console.log(EstimatedTime)
                }else if(EstimatedTime<2100){
                    $('#prefiller').addClass('fill-fast')
                    console.log(perfData.loadEventEnd)
                    console.log(perfData.navigationStart)
                    console.log(EstimatedTime)
                }else if(EstimatedTime<2800){
                    $('#prefiller').addClass('fill-slow')
                    console.log(perfData.loadEventEnd)
                    console.log(perfData.navigationStart)
                    console.log(EstimatedTime)
                }else {
                    $('#prefiller').addClass('fill-vslow')
                    console.log(perfData.loadEventEnd)
                    console.log(perfData.navigationStart)
                    console.log(EstimatedTime)
                }
            });  // Executes 10 ms after load has ended
        };  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- #preloader -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="preloader-logo">
            <img src="/logo.png" onload="loadTime();">
            <div class="grayscaler" id="prefiller"><img src="/logo.png"></div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#preloader -->
```

Comment: Are you really trying to show the progress of one image (cause I think that will be tough , or are looking to show progress for something else? window.performance.timing displays information related to the document itself, not to a specific element.

Comment: The images themselves work perfectly. The effect achieved is a grayscale version of the logo, and it slowly fills up with color.

What I was hoping to do was assign different classes based on estimated pageload-speed, since each class will make the CSS animation have a different speed.

Is there any way to do this?